# problem with sql query (nested AND OR)

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I'm trying to use the following query but its not getting any records:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id) 
WHERE ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (92) ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future') 
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_inicio_date' 
AND mt1.meta_key = '_inicio_date' 
AND mt2.meta_key = '_eventtimestamp' 
AND ( (mt1.meta_value BETWEEN 20110201 AND 20110231) OR (mt2.meta_value BETWEEN 20110201 AND 20110231) ) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date asc
```

But, If I do:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)   
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id) 
WHERE ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (92) ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future') 
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_inicio_date' 
AND mt1.meta_key = '_inicio_date' 
AND mt2.meta_key = '_eventtimestamp' 
AND (mt1.meta_value BETWEEN 20110201 AND 20110231) 
OR (mt2.meta_value BETWEEN 20110201 AND 20110231) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date asc
```

It gets records, but ignores all the previos "AND" for the records found with "OR"

How can I nest the last "AND" and "OR"?

Thanks

Comment: What is the desired condition, please explain ... With which condition results are failing, please share your analysis.....

Comment: The condition AND ( (mt1.meta_value BETWEEN 20110201 AND 20110231) OR (mt2.meta_value BETWEEN 20110201 AND 20110231) )

Comment: The condition "AND ( (mt1.meta_value BETWEEN 20110201 AND 20110231) OR (mt2.meta_value BETWEEN 20110201 AND 20110231) )" is failing, it finds no records

Comment: @Mario, as Nitin suggested, that is the way to nest the two conditions.  You probably don't have any records where that satisfy all the conditions you specified in #1.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you actually have records that satisfy the first statement?

Comment: Are you sure there are records that match either of those conditions? The second one will get any records that have a mt2.meta_value between 20110201 and 20110231 regardless of all your other constraints. Is it possible there aren't any that match all of the constraints? You're doing a lot of string comparisons in the earlier constraints, is it possible some of those aren't exact matches?

Comment: If we comment the AND condition you mentioned, how does records looks like without this AND condition, what are the values for mt1.meta_value and mt2.meta_value ...

Comment: Maybe im not being clear: I want the last condition "AND ( (mt1.meta_value BETWEEN 20110201 AND 20110231) OR (mt2.meta_value BETWEEN 20110201 AND 20110231) )" to find any record that has mt1.meta_value or mt2.meta_value between those values

Comment: Hmmm...So, can you just use: "OR ((mt1.meta_value BETWEEN 20110201 AND 20110231) OR (mt2.meta_value BETWEEN 20110201 AND 20110231))"? This will get you any records that have meta_values between those dates OR that match all the other criteria.

Comment: I think condition is fine, there might be some other condition filtering the record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked using this:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id) 
WHERE ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (".$categoria.") ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private' OR     wp_posts.post_status = 'future') 
AND ( ( mt1.meta_key = '_incio_date' AND (mt1.meta_value BETWEEN 20110201 AND 20110231) ) OR (mt2.meta_key = '_eventtimestamp' AND (mt2.meta_value BETWEEN 20110201 AND 20110231) ) )
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date asc
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that one entry in wp_posts may not have both connected records in wp_postmeta table, so change

```
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id)
```

to

```
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id)
```

One more thing: be careful when you use BETWEEN:

For best results when using BETWEEN with date or time values, use CAST() to explicitly convert the values to the desired data type. Examples: If you compare a DATETIME to two DATE values, convert the DATE values to DATETIME values. If you use a string constant such as '2001-1-1' in a comparison to a DATE, cast the string to a DATE.

Comment: It didnt work, I tried using with and without brackets in the last 2 conditions: AND (mt1.meta_value BETWEEN 20110201 AND 20110231) 
OR (mt2.meta_value BETWEEN 20110201 AND 20110231)

Comment: Are you sure you have the record in the database satisfying the query??

Comment: Maybe im not being clear: I want the last condition "AND ( (mt1.meta_value BETWEEN 20110201 AND 20110231) OR (mt2.meta_value BETWEEN 20110201 AND 20110231) )" to find any record that has mt1.meta_value or mt2.meta_value between those values

Comment: I was using CAST, but I removed to check if it was causing the error